# Where do I place my property file in java web project?

Tags: servlets, properties, filter

I am working on a web project. I want to know where should I put my property file. I will use it for filters. I attached a screenshot of my project too. 
Thanks!

[image: My project]

Comment: Unable to see attachment

Comment: @BhargavKumarR http://i.stack.imgur.com/6d8Km.jpg Do you see it now i copied it here.

Comment: Not able to see..better you insert in ur question

Comment: @BhargavKumarR : I tried that but the website said I need 10 reputation to attach any pictures. So there is that.

Comment: @BhargavKumarR thanks xD i attached it.

Comment: It depends entirely on how you load (or intend to load) the properties file in the first place. If you load it using the ClassLoader, then place it in the sources, with your Java files. If you load it as a webapp resource, using the ServletContext, place it under WebContent/WEB-INF. If you want it to be avdownloadable from the browser, then put it anywhere under WebContent, except in WEB-INF.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you kind Sir, It's loaded now and working. Thanks

Comment: @BhargavKumarR Thanks to you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends entirely on how you load (or intend to load) the properties file in the first place. If you load it using the ClassLoader, then place it in the sources, with your Java files. If you load it as a webapp resource, using the ServletContext, place it under WebContent/WEB-INF. If you want it to be avdownloadable from the browser, then put it anywhere under WebContent, except in WEB-INF. – JB Nizet
https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet